# Get Camera Animated On Path In Aframe To Stay Focused On A Subject

Tags: javascript, three.js, aframe

I have a camera that is animated using the alongpath component and I want the camera to stay focused on a target. I've tried using both orbit-controls and look-at components with no luck. For some reason, I can get them either to either do nothing or just their own crazy thing with no logic. Part of me feels like there could be a conflict between these and the alongpath component maybe? I'd love any advice on this!

Here is a glitch with what I am working with, along with both methods of orbit-controls + look-at that I used. https://glitch.com/edit/#!/aframe-camera-focus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up getting it to work! I removed the rotation portion from the alongpath component, made the camera rig into just one  entity and then applied look-at to it. https://glitch.com/edit/#!/aframe-alongpath-test

Comment: The links (both question link and answer link) are not working. Please update if you have a link to sample of camera animated on a path, using aframe. Thanks.

Comment: @RodrigoDeAlmeidaSiqueira I've updated the links below. I moved on to ThreeJs so I'm rusty on Aframe now. https://glitch.com/edit/#!/aframe-alongpath-test  https://glitch.com/edit/#!/aframe-alongpath-scroll